# timing issue in OFDM

Tags: ofdm, symbol-timing

suppose I have this OFDM signal the pink part is cyclic prefix. I should sample at point b. Because of lack of Timing I started to sample at point a, but I get wrong detection. How can I compensate this problem. I appreciate any help.
[image]

Comment: "I should sample at point b" Absolutely not. You should sample earlier, within the CP. a is right, b is wrong.

Comment: Yes. If I sample at a, the phase of signal changes and detection goes wrong. What do I do for compensating phase?

Comment: No, if you sample at a, you're doing it right. If you sample at b, your last sample is already in the next symbol, and you introduce inter-symbol interference. You can't fix that. Again: You should **not** sample at b.